# HTML5/JavaScript comparing two randomly generated numbers

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, random, html5-canvas

so I'm making a game where I open boxes by clicking them on the HTML5 Canvas and try to match the numbers inside the box (long story short, getting a match = a win, i.e. 1st box could be a 5, if the 2nd box is also 5, I win).

When a box is clicked, a random number is generated between a certain range. What I need is a way to compare the numbers that are generated to check if the player has won or if they need to continue opening boxes.

The boxes work like so:

```
    var rect = {
        x: 30,
        y: 150,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    };

    function getMousePos(canvas, event) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: event.clientX - rect.left,
            y: event.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
```

I had thought about storing the randomly generated number, like so:

```
var firstChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 5 + 1) + 10);
var secondChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 5 + 1) + 10);
```

But I don't know how to have the program recognise when secondChoice, thirdChoice, fourthChoice etc. needs to be run for the next boxes instead of firstChoice.

Any tips?

Comment: When you have a list of variables it's time to use an array for storage.

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. if each box corresponds to a variable, then after each click, you can compare the two variables and check if they are equal. You'll need to add more code/details

Comment: @smythdev if you're simply asking how to persist the storage of the values, you could use sessionStorage that would persist the values for the duration of the browser session on the client. But it is not very clear what you're asking

Comment: @AdamMcGurk hi, what I'm asking is how to have the program recognise when to use the other variables. i.e. the first box opening would be firstChoice, the second box opened would be secondChoice, etc.

Comment: @smythdev can you give me an example of what these "boxes" look like in code? That will help alot

Comment: @AdamMcGurk I added some code to the original post. I then have an event listener which checks if the player is clicking inside the box area, and if they are, it runs a separate function which generates the random number. What I want to be able to do is store that random number, then when a second box is opened and a new random number is given, compare the two to check for a win.

Comment: @smythdev OK, and you're looking for an exact match? For example, for a player to win both numbers would have to be exactly identical?

Comment: @AdamMcGurk Yes, and a third/fourth box would need to be opened if no match is found.

Comment: @smythdev added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a way to store and compare data...I would use sessionStorage to store the first one clicked, and then compare off that until a match is found:

```
// Player clicks box and generates number before the following function is called
function checkNumber(randomNumberGeneratedByRandomNumberGenerator) {

    // Checks to see if there is a number already stored
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("firstNumberClicked")) {

        // Retrieve the stored number to use for comparison
        const firstNumberClicked = sessionStorage.getItem("firstNumberClicked");

        // Compare numbers, if they are exactly equal, hooray for user...if not, boo for user.
        if (firstNumberClicked == randomNumberGeneratedByRandomNumberGenerator) {
            alert("hooray, you won user!!!!");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("firstNumberClicked");
        } else {
            alert("sorry user, better luck next time :(");
        }
    } else {

        // There is not a number that already exists in storage, store the number passed to the function
        sessionStorage.setItem("firstNumberClicked", randomNumberGeneratedByRandomNumberGenerator);
    }
}
```

Call this function immediately after you generate your random number

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go now. Is there anything in there that needs replacing? Like variable names?

Comment: @smythdev the only thing that needs replacing is replace `randomNumberGeneratedByRandomNumberGenerator` with the return from your function that generates the random number.

Comment: Getting there, but it doesn't seem to be quite right. As soon as the first box is opened, it declares a loss, whereas that shouldn't be possible when only one box has been opened. If it does let me open 2 boxes, sometimes it will give a loss even if the 2 random numbers are the same. It seems like it's remembering old numbers.

Comment: @smythdev edit your original post and show me how you're calling all of your functions, because it works for me

Comment: @smythdev how are you calling `randomBox()`?

Comment: In my .html file which is just used for laying the game graphics out. The clickable areas for the boxes are clicked, it runs randomBox().

Comment: @smythdev So I edited the code slightly up top, and that worked for me putting it in the console.

Comment: So what that does is immediately displays the alert inside randomBox() without displaying any graphics. Remember I only want randomBox() to be called when a box is clicked.
If I just change the === to ==, it works but what I'm noticing is that the every time I click a box it calls firstChoice, which has the same random number stored in it, so it's always a win. That's why I had the other variables, secondChoice, thirdChoice etc. to generate a brand new random number, but I don't know how to have the program call them once firstChoice has been used.

Comment: Ok new development, I moved the declaration of firstChoice into randomBox() instead of at the beginning of the program, and also added "sessionStorage.removeItem("firstNumberClicked"); to the lose statement as well, and now it seems to be working as I want it to. Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: @smythdev yeah man, we all start somewhere and we're all learning. Have fun coding :)